# Enlarge an image on mouse hover

Tags: c#, .net

I want a picture in my windows form application to enlarge on mouse hover and go back to it's normal size when the mouse leaves the picture.

I couldn't find an answer on Stack Overflow but I figured it out and I want to leave my answer for any c# beginners like me.

Comment: What kind of app is this?  Approaches will vary greatly based on this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very simple solution but it worked for my basic needs.

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(90, 60); // Desired hovered size
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(60, 30); // Back to original size
}
```